# Solo me guarda 100 lineas en el fichero

Tags: java

estoy intentando hacer un script en java para que me guarde en un fichero las ips con el puerto 22 abierto y para ello utilizo la api de shodan y sus librerias para java. El problema es que el script solo me escribe las 100 primeras IPs en el fichero y me gustaria guardar todas las Ips dentro del fichero para tener un registro de todas y no solo las 100 primeras que encuentra. Muchas gracias.

```
import com.fooock.shodan.ShodanRestApi;
import com.fooock.shodan.model.banner.Banner;
import com.fooock.shodan.model.host.HostReport;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import io.reactivex.observers.DisposableObserver;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Recolectar {

    public void capturarIP() {
        ShodanRestApi api = new ShodanRestApi("KEY");

        api.hostSearch("port:22").subscribe(new DisposableObserver<HostReport>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                // called if an error occurs
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(HostReport hostReport) {
                FileWriter archivo = null;
                PrintWriter pw = null;
                int total = hostReport.getTotal();
                List<Banner> banners = hostReport.getBanners();

                System.out.println("Se han encontrado " + total + " IPs");

                try {
                    archivo = new FileWriter("ip.txt");
                    pw = new PrintWriter(archivo);

                    for (int x = 0; x <= banners.size()-1; x++) {
                        pw.println(banners.get(x).getIpStr());
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        // Nuevamente aprovechamos el finally para
                        // asegurarnos que se cierra el fichero.
                        if (null != archivo)
                            archivo.close();
                    } catch (Exception e2) {
                        e2.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        });


    }
```

Comment: Según explica [la documentación de la API](https://developer.shodan.io/api), en el apartado `/shodan/host/search`, **los resultados vienen paginados de 100 en 100**, así que ese es el motivo por el que sólo obtienes 100 resultados. Entonces supongo que la API tendrá algún modo de moverte entre las páginas para ir recuperando los resultados de 100 en 100. La doc también dice que por cada página te van a deducir un crédito de consulta.

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a la API solo se pueden entregar 100 resultados como máximo por cada página usando la petición:

[/shodan/host/search](https://developer.shodan.io/api)

pero puedes pedir paginas de 100 en 100 agregando el número de la página en tu petición:

> https://api.shodan.io/shodan/host/search?key={YOUR_API_KEY}&query={query}&facets={facets}**&page={número
>   de página}**

---

Esta es la información relacionada al parámetro `page`:

> `page` (optional): [Integer] El número de página para recorrer los
>   resultados 100 a la vez (predeterminado: 1)

---

Para obtener el total de páginas, al realizar esta petición puedes ver que te entrega el total de los elementos, ejemplo:

```
  ...
  ...
 },
 "total": 12039
}
```

si divides entre 100 obtendras 12039/100 = 121 páginas. Por lo tanto para obtener los datos totales deberás realizar peticiones por cada número de página:

```
https://api.shodan.io/shodan/host/search?key={YOUR_API_KEY}&query={query}&facets={facets}&page=1
https://api.shodan.io/shodan/host/search?key={YOUR_API_KEY}&query={query}&facets={facets}&page=2
https://api.shodan.io/shodan/host/search?key={YOUR_API_KEY}&query={query}&facets={facets}&page=3
...
...
...

https://api.shodan.io/shodan/host/search?key={YOUR_API_KEY}&query={query}&facets={facets}&page=120
https://api.shodan.io/shodan/host/search?key={YOUR_API_KEY}&query={query}&facets={facets}&page=121
```